# How to add some external package with nwidart/laravel-modules?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

In Laravel 6/nwidart/laravel-modules 7 app I see file composer.json in root of my module
with lines :

```
{
    "name": "nwidart/pages",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nicolas Widart",
            "email": "n.widart@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [],
            "aliases": {

            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\Pages\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that if I want to add some external package into my module(not the whole app)
I need to edit this file and run module commands?
How have I to edit it and which commands to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular `composer` commands in the module directory. Just `cd` into it then use `composer require package-name`.

Comment: Thanks! Also as for npm packages? Similar rules ?

Comment: Pls look also at UPDATED:

Comment: That's a different question. You should roll back your changes and ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

After adding an entry to the compose file using e.g. in folder your module

```
composer require package-name
```

Use the command in the main application in folder global application

```
php artisan module:update name-your-module
```